# Continuity, proving a function at a point is continuous

Tags: calculus, continuity

Prove, by using the definition of continuity, that $()=\frac{5}{3} \sqrt{}+3$
is continuous at the point $ = 7$.

I'm confused on how to go about tackling such a question.
Thank you

Comment: For starters, write down the definition -- that will tell you what you need to prove.

Answer (score 1):

Continuity means that the closer $x$ gets to $7$, the closer $f(x)$ gets to $f(7)$. More precisely, if you constrain $f(x)$ to lie in a given neighborhood of $f(7)$, it must be possible to find a neighborhood of $7$ that achieves that constraint.

In formula,

$$\forall \epsilon>0, \exists\delta>0,|x-7|<\delta\implies|f(x)-f(7)|<\epsilon.$$

Now replacing by the particular expressions,

$$\forall \epsilon>0, \exists\delta>0,|x-7|<\delta\implies\frac53\left|\sqrt x-\sqrt 7\right|<\epsilon.$$

The last inequality can be reworked with

$$|\sqrt x-\sqrt7|=\frac{|x-7|}{\sqrt x+\sqrt 7}\le\frac{|x-7|}{\sqrt 7}$$

so that

$$|x-7|<\delta\implies \frac53\left|\sqrt x-\sqrt 7\right|\le\frac5{3\sqrt 7}\left|x-7\right|<\frac5{3\sqrt 7}\delta.$$

This shows that if we set $\delta=\dfrac{3\sqrt7}5\epsilon$, which is possible for any $\epsilon$, the required condition is achieved and the function is continuous at $x=7$.